# Javascript error when converting zipcode to latlng in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using random user generator to get a zip code everytime I click on the button. And that works fine. But when I try to send the zipcode to google maps geolocation I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: zipcode is not defined    script.js:22
```

Any help?

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">   

      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(16.4706001, -33.6728973),
          zoom:3,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);    
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

    <div id="button">
      <button id="loadbutton">Click to Load</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var randomuserURL = 'http://api.randomuser.me/';

var myButton = document.getElementById('loadbutton');
myButton.onclick = loadAJAX;

function loadAJAX () {
    var zipcode;
    $.ajax({
      url: randomuserURL,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        zipcode = data.results[0].user.location.zip;
      }
    });

    latlng();
}

function latlng() {
    var lat = '';
    var lng = '';
    var address = zipcode;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
             lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
    alert('Latitude: ' + lat + ' Logitude: ' + lng);
}
```

Comment: You need to define `zipcode` in the global scope, not in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function loadAJAX() {
   var zipcode;
    $.ajax({
        url: randomuserURL,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            zipcode = data.results[0].user.location.zip;
            latlng(zipcode);
        }
    }); 
}
```

And in

```
function latlng(zipcode) {
............
...........
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked too. But the mistakes on my code are too many. Right now I've fixed the scope variable and then defining `var geocode = new google.maps.Geocoder();` And finally is working but now at the first click I'm getting `ZERO_RESULTS` and from the second time I click I'm getting the latitude and longitude

Comment: Also when I go to google maps and search with the zipcode I need to search twice the first time I put a zipcode. Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

You define your `zipcode` in the first function and trying to access it in another, where the variable is not known.
You need to place your `zipcode` variable in the global scope so other functions can access it too.

And pointed out by Ashley Medway: `latlng()` should be triggered in the `success` function. This is because AJAX is asynchronous and might not be finished when you triggered the function.

```
var randomuserURL = 'http://api.randomuser.me/';
var zipcode;
var myButton = document.getElementById('loadbutton');
myButton.onclick = loadAJAX;

function loadAJAX() {
    $.ajax({
        url: randomuserURL,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            zipcode = data.results[0].user.location.zip;

            latlng();
        }
    });

}

function latlng() {
    var lat = '';
    var lng = '';
    var address = zipcode;
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
    alert('Latitude: ' + lat + ' Logitude: ' + lng);
}
```

Also: you might need to define `var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();` and include `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script>`

Comment: also `latlng()` should appear in the success block, as the ajax code is asynchronous

Comment: I have fixed the scope variable and included the latlng() in success but now I'm getting "geocoder is not defined". Geocoder is the google maps call. Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: I have solved that one. The issue was to define var geocode = new google.maps.Geocoder(); And finally is working but at the first click I'm getting ZERO_RESULTS and from the second time I click I'm getting the latitude and longitude. Also when I go to google maps and search with the zipcode I need to search twice the first time I put a zipcode. Hope this help.